# Is it necessary to paint over window glazing?

Tags: windows, painting

When replacing a window pane in an old wooden window sash, after the window has been glazed is it necessary to paint over the glaze, or is it OK to leave it unpainted?

Answer (score 4):

The product I most often use for glazing wood sash windows (DAP 33 Glazing Compound) **must** be painted or it will shrink and pull away from the glass.

Unfortunately the stuff takes a while to firm up, like at least a week. If you mess with it before it skins over and firms up, it will deform. Also, because it is an oil-based product you have to paint it with oil based paint (or you can use oil based primer then paint over that with water-based paint). You should lap your paint over the line where the putty meets the glass, to seal the gap between glazing putty and glass.

Comment: I'm using an Ace branded glazing compound, and I'm assuming that this is similar or identical to the DAP 33 compound.  Do there exist compounds that don't ever need to be painted?